# Do I need a seperate SQL Server license for Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: tfs

I am installing TFS 2010, and it does not install SQL and sharepoint automatically. I am assuming I need to manually install this.

Do I need a serpeate license ontop of the TFS license?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TFS 2010 gives you a license to SQL Server 2008 Standard edition for the sole purpose of using it as a TFS Database. <strike>The database must also be installed on the same server as TFS application tier.</strike> This is explained in detail in the [Visual Studio 2010 licensing whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2b1504e6-0bf1-46da-be0e-85cc792c6b9d&displaylang=en).

It is best to install SQL Server and Sharepoint (Foundation or MOSS) before you start TFS install and then TFS can be configured to use this in post-install steps. The [TFS installation guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2d531219-2c39-4c69-88ef-f5ae6ac18c9f&displaylang=en) is extremely useful. I have just gone through this process myself.

Comment: Actually, you're not required to install SQL Server on the same server as the TFS App Tier. Dual-server configurations are fine so long as you only deploy one instance of SQL Server 2008 for each instance of TFS 2010 you deploy.

Comment: This may in the latest licensing option. I installed based on this [whitepaper dated Feb 2010] (http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/B/1/7B18407A-AC79-4949-A318-A6636D96F497/Visual%20Studio%202010%20Licensing%20-%20Feb-2010.pdf)  that said ( *However, SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition must be deployed 
on the same devices as Team Foundation Server and can only be used to support Team Foundation Server—not  for any other purposes.* )

Comment: This has changed for TFS 2012: _This is not a separate SQL Server license. This instance of SQL Server **can run on a separate server** but can only be used by Team Foundation Server—not for any other purposes._ How to aqcuire the installation files, I don't know. Source: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350